# gunicorn + redis: Does not work?

Tags: django, caching, redis, gunicorn

I run a Django server with redis [in-memory caching for filtering duplicate records] integrated to a celery process [tasks that insert data into a PostgreSQL database asynchronously]. The django server is integrated with redis via `django-redis-cache` with caching enabled.

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': '/tmp/redis.sock',
  },
}
```

If I use `./manage.py runserver ip:8000` to run my server and start posting data, there's no problem during GET/SET attributes in redis as it is a single application and my app runs smoothly.

But now, I'm planning to migrate the django to `gunicorn` via this command:

```
gunicorn myapp:wsgi_app -w 3 -b ip:8000
```

As this creates 3 workers for django process, I believe they are trying to access the same redis-server for caching.

If I start posting data using this setup, I get this message,

```
Internal Server Error: /post/data/
 File "/path/to/app/views.py", line 94, in saveData
   value = cache.get(key)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis_cache/cache.py", line 186, in get
   result = self.unpickle(value)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/redis_cache/cache.py", line 248, in unpickle
   return pickle.loads(value)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1035, in model_unpickle
   return cls.__new__(cls)
 TypeError: ('object.__new__(X): X is not a type object (NoneType)', <function model_unpickle at 0x1c49aa0>, ((u'webapi', 'Reading'), [], <function simple_class_factory at 0x1c49a28>))
```

If I check the redis-server log [`redis-cli monitor`], I get empty records in them after I start using gunicorn.

Is there a smart work around to keep redis active for gunicorn threads also?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like an error occurs when Redis Cache un-pickle a object.

the reason is Django can't find the model `(u'webapi', 'Reading')`,

check whether have you added `webapi` app into settings.INSTALLED_APPS.